# Optimizing throughput for my malloc function

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I have my own malloc function with an explicit free list to manage the space in the heap. The space use is regulated almost perfect but my throughput is super slow, any ideas on what I could do about it ? It is allready a first fit (LIFO), anything else does not sound faster in my ears.

This memory allocator implements an explicit free list for efficient memory management.
The allocator uses heap space for memory allocation. Each block on the heap is either allocated
for use or part of the free list managing unused space.

Block Structure:
Each block, whether allocated or free, includes a header and a footer. The header and footer
each contain a block size indicator and an allocation bit (0 for free, 1 for allocated), with the
minimum block size being 16 bytes (including 8 bytes for the payload and 4 bytes each for te
header and footer).

In the explicit free list, free blocks also contain pointers to the next and previous free
blocks within their payload space. This facilitates efficient traversal and manipulation of free
blocks. Additionally, we implement prologue and epilogue blocks to handle edge cases in te free
list management.

```
#define ALIGNMENT         8         // memory alignment factor
#define WSIZE             4         // Size in bytes of a single word 
#define DSIZE             8         // Size in bytes of a double word
#define INITSIZE          16        // Initial size of free list before first free block added
#define MINBLOCKSIZE      16        /* Minmum size for a free block, includes 4 bytes for header/footer
                                       and space within the payload for two pointers to the prev and next
                                       free blocks */

/* rounds up to the nearest multiple of ALIGNMENT */
#define ALIGN(size) (((size) + (ALIGNMENT-1)) & ~0x7)


#define SIZE_T_SIZE (ALIGN(sizeof(size_t)))


/* Some basic Macros and Constants which I have foung in the book "Computer systems: A programmers perspective
 * Page 893 Figure 9.43
 * Basic constants and macros */


#define ALIGN(size) (((size) + (ALIGNMENT-1)) & ~0x7)
#define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y)? (x) : (y))
#define PACK(size, alloc) ((size) | (alloc))
#define GET(p)        (*(size_t *)(p))
#define PUT(p, val)   (*(size_t *)(p) = (val))
#define GET_SIZE(p)  (GET(p) & ~0x1)
#define GET_ALLOC(p) (GET(p) & 0x1)
#define HDRP(bp)     ((void *)(bp) - WSIZE)
#define FTRP(bp)     ((void *)(bp) + GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp)) - DSIZE)

#define NEXT_BLKP(bp) ((void *)(bp) + GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp)))
#define PREV_BLKP(bp) ((void *)(bp) - GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp) - WSIZE))
#define NEXT_FREE(bp)(*(void **)(bp))
#define PREV_FREE(bp)(*(void **)(bp + WSIZE))
 

/* Prototypes */
static void remove_freeblock(void *bp);
static void *extend_heap (size_t words);
static void *coalesce (void *bp);
static void *find_fit (size_t asize);
static void  place (void *bp, size_t asize);
void *mm_malloc(size_t size);




static char *heap_list = 0;
static char *free_list = 0;

int mm_init(void)
{
    
    /* Create empty Heap */
    if ((heap_list = mem_sbrk(INITSIZE + MINBLOCKSIZE)) == (void *)-1)
        return -1;
    
    PUT(heap_list,              PACK(MINBLOCKSIZE, 1)); //  Prologue
    PUT(heap_list + (1*WSIZE),  PACK(MINBLOCKSIZE, 0)); //  Free block Header
    PUT(heap_list + (2*WSIZE),  PACK(0, 0));            //  Pointer to next free (space)
    PUT(heap_list + (3*WSIZE),  PACK(0, 0));            //  Pointer to previous free (space)
    PUT(heap_list + (4*WSIZE),  PACK(MINBLOCKSIZE, 0));  //  Free block footer
    PUT(heap_list + (5*WSIZE),  PACK(0, 1));            //  Epilogue
    free_list   =   heap_list + (WSIZE);
    
    

    
    
    return 0;

}


void *mm_malloc(size_t size)
{
    

    size_t asize ;
    
    void *bp;

    // Ignore useless allocation
    if(size == 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Adjust the blocksize to include header and footer
    if(size <= DSIZE)
        asize = MINBLOCKSIZE;
    else
        // Align the size and add space for the header and footer
        asize = ALIGN(size) + DSIZE;
    
    // Search the free list for a fit, if found, place it.
    if ((bp = find_fit(asize)) != NULL)
    {

        place(bp, asize);
        return bp;
    }


    /* If there is no free space anymore, extend the Heap and then place it */
    
    if((bp = extend_heap(asize/WSIZE)) == NULL)
    {

        return NULL;

    }

    place(bp, asize);

    return bp;


}

/*
 * mm_free - Freeing a block does nothing.
 */
void mm_free(void *bp)
{

    size_t size = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));
    PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
    PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
    coalesce(bp);
}

/*
 * mm_realloc - Implemented simply in terms of mm_malloc and mm_free
 */
void *mm_realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
{
    /*
     * ATTENTION: You do not need to implement realloc for this assignment
     */

    void *oldptr = ptr;
    void *newptr;
    size_t copySize;

    newptr = mm_malloc(size);
    if (newptr == NULL)
      return NULL;
    copySize = *(size_t *)((char *)oldptr - SIZE_T_SIZE);
    if (size < copySize)
      copySize = size;
    memcpy(newptr, oldptr, copySize);
    mm_free(oldptr);
    return newptr;
}

// Helper functions


/* Function to extend the size of the heap */

static void *extend_heap (size_t words)
{


    char *bp;
    size_t size;
    
    /* Allocate an even number of words to maintain alignment */
    
    size = (words % 2) ? (words + 1) * WSIZE : words * WSIZE;

    if ((bp = mem_sbrk(size)) == -1 ) 
    {   

        return NULL;
    }
    
    /* Initialize free block header / footer and the epilogue header */
    PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));   //Free block header
    PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));   //Free block footer
    PUT(HDRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)), PACK(0, 1));   //New Epiloge Header
    
    /* Coalesce if the previous block was free */
    return coalesce(bp);
}


static void *coalesce(void *bp)
{


    size_t prev_alloc = GET_ALLOC(FTRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)))||PREV_BLKP(bp) == bp;
    size_t next_alloc = GET_ALLOC(HDRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
    size_t size = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));         

    
    /* Case1 : The previos and the next block are both allocated*/
    if ( prev_alloc && next_alloc )
    {

        PREV_FREE(free_list) = bp;
        NEXT_FREE(bp) = free_list;
        PREV_FREE(bp) = NULL;
        free_list = bp;

        return bp; 
    }

    /* Case2 : The previos block is allocates and the next block is free */
    else if ( prev_alloc && !next_alloc) 
    {

        size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
        remove_freeblock(NEXT_BLKP(bp));
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
    }

    /* The previos block is free and the next block is allocated */
    else if (!prev_alloc && next_alloc )
    {
        
        
        size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)));
        


        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(size, 0));
        PUT(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size,0));
        bp = PREV_BLKP(bp);
        remove_freeblock(bp);
    }

    /* The previos and the next block are both free */
    else if (!prev_alloc && !next_alloc)
    {
        size += GET_SIZE(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp))) +
        GET_SIZE(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)));
        remove_freeblock(PREV_BLKP(bp));
        remove_freeblock(NEXT_BLKP(bp));
        PUT(HDRP(PREV_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size,0));
        PUT(FTRP(NEXT_BLKP(bp)), PACK(size,0));
        bp = PREV_BLKP(bp);
    }
   

    PREV_FREE(free_list) = bp;
    NEXT_FREE(bp) = free_list;
    PREV_FREE(bp) = NULL;
    free_list = bp;

    return bp;
}



static void *find_fit(size_t asize)
{
    

    // Iterate through the free list to find a suitable block
    void *bp;
    
    for (bp = free_list; GET_ALLOC(HDRP(bp)) == 0; bp = NEXT_FREE(bp))
    {
        
        // Check if the block is free and large enough
        if (GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp)) >= asize)
        {

            return bp; // Suitable block found
        }
    }
    return NULL; // No suitable block found
}




static void place(void* bp, size_t asize)
{


    // Retrieve the size of the entire free block
    size_t bsize = GET_SIZE(HDRP(bp));

    // Check if the remaining space after allocation is sufficient for splitting
    if ((bsize - asize) >= MINBLOCKSIZE)
    {
        // Allocate the required space and adjust the remaining free block
        // The new header and footer are set up for the remaining free space
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(asize, 1));
        remove_freeblock(bp); // Remove the block from the free list
        bp = NEXT_BLKP(bp);   // Move to the next block
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(bsize - asize, 0)); // Set header for the new free block
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(bsize - asize, 0)); // Set footer for the new free block
        coalesce(bp); // Coalesce if adjacent blocks are free
    }
    else
    {
        // Allocate the entire block if splitting is not feasible
        PUT(HDRP(bp), PACK(bsize, 1));
        PUT(FTRP(bp), PACK(bsize, 1));
        remove_freeblock(bp); // Remove the block from the free list
    }
    
}



 
static void remove_freeblock(void *bp)
{


    if(bp) {  // Ensure bp is not NULL

    // Adjust the previous block's next pointer
    // If there is a previous free block, update its next pointer to skip the current block.
    // If there is no previous block, reset the start of the free list to the next free block.
    if (PREV_FREE(bp))
      NEXT_FREE(PREV_FREE(bp)) = NEXT_FREE(bp);
    else
      free_list = NEXT_FREE(bp);

    // Adjust the next block's previous pointer
    // If there is a next free block, update its previous pointer to skip the current block.
    if(NEXT_FREE(bp) != NULL)
      PREV_FREE(NEXT_FREE(bp)) = PREV_FREE(bp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good time to fire up the profiler and figure out where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Once the profiler finds the bottlenecks, only optimize the *top one* bottleneck. If performance is still not meeting the requirements you have, then do it again, profile and optimize only the top one bottleneck. And remember that good enough really is good enough.

Comment: I did not knew about a profiler before and just tryed it out, turns out that the bottleneck is the mm_malloc function itself which calls all the other functions. How can that be ?

Comment: @Alabama92,  posted code is not fully compliable.  Consider a [mcve] to improve the question.

Comment: @Alabama92 I'm assuming time spent in functions called by mm_malloc is counted into time spent in mm_malloc by the profiler.